# Loading components separately inside UI

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I'm trying to simulate an accelerated view of a Facebook feed, so the components must show up one by one on the page (without refreshing). The way I went about it was to create different threads that each sleep a certain amount of time and then add a Label (or something else) to the layout, but instead of these components showing up one by one, the whole UI is waiting for all the threads to finish sleeping and running. Is there a functional method of achieving this in Vaadin?

```
 protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();       
    setContent(layout);
        layout.addComponent(new Label("this shows up first"));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        layout.addComponent(new Label("this shows up after sleeping"));
}
```

Comment: Background threads are the correct way to do it. Please show your code

Comment: Here's the code. I was expecting to have the second Label appear after a 5000 ms delay, instead I just get both at the same time. @Push is enabled.

Comment: You Block the main thread. You need to spawn a new Thread and then and the label there. Don't forget to syncronise access in the Background thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603492/using-thread-with-vaadin